# Foreign key lookups - slug URL with Django generic list view

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have been searching here and reading the documentation and experimenting in python, but I can't find a solution to my particular mess. I did the Django tutorial, but I'm still confused as to how to pass stuff thru the URL in django when starting to use foreign keys, I'm sure it's pretty simple. I'm a new django user and this is my first post. I have the models Playlist, and PlaylistEntry with mixed relationships to user and videos (not posted). I'm trying to show a detail view that uses a slug of a playlist title, to pull out entries in the playlist. Eg. In python, I can do

```
    entries = PlaylistEntry.objects.filter(playlist__slug='django')
```

which returns all my entries in the playlist 'Django' correctly.

Here are my models...

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'playliztz'


    title = models.CharField(blank=True, 
        help_text=u'Title of playlist',
        max_length=64,
        )

    user = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.UserProfile', 
        blank=False,
        help_text=u'owns this playlist',
        null=False, )


    slug = models.SlugField(u'slug',
        max_length=160,
        blank=True,
        editable=False
        )

    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('playlist-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def save(self):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        if not self.id:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.today()
        self.modified = datetime.datetime.today()
        super(Playlist,self).save() 


class PlaylistEntry(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "playlist entries"

    video = models.ForeignKey('video.Video',
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        help_text=u'the video title',
        null=True, )

    playlist = models.ForeignKey('Playlist', 
        blank=True,
        default=None,
        help_text=u'Belongs to this playlist',
        null=True,)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.video.video_title
```

My URLS looks like this...

```
    url(r'^playlist/$', PlaylistList.as_view(), name='user_playlists'),
    url(r'^playlist/(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$', PlaylistDetail.as_view(), name='playlist_entries'),
```

And my Views.py looks like this...

```
    class PlaylistList(LoggedInMixin, ListView): # shows a list of playlists
        template_name = 'userprofile/playlist_list.html'
        model = Playlist
        context_object_name = 'playlist_list'

        def get_queryset(self):
            """Return currently users playlists."""
            return Playlist.objects.filter(user__user=self.request.user)

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(PlaylistList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            if not self.get_queryset():
                context['error'] = "You don't have any playlists yet."
                return context 
            else:
                return context

    class PlaylistDetail(LoggedInMixin, DetailView):
        model = PlaylistEntry
        template_name = 'userprofile/playlist_detail.html'

        def get_queryset(self):
            self.current_playlist = get_object_or_404(Playlist, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])

            # CHECK - Prints out correct entries for playlist in slugfield (current_playlist)
            self.entries = PlaylistEntry.objects.filter(playlist__title=self.current_playlist.title)
            print self.entries 

            # Should expect to return the same queryset?
            return PlaylistEntry.objects.filter(playlist__title=self.current_playlist.title)


        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(PlaylistEntry, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['entries'] = PlaylistEntry.objects.all()
            return context
```

self.entries prints the correct entries for this playlist in the Check bit.

In my playlist template I am using a link sending the playlist.slug - the url looks correct like this /user/playlist/this-particular-playlist-slug.

the error is...

```
    Cannot resolve keyword u'slug' into field. Choices are: id, playlist, video
```

Comment: Please don't snip the traceback. We need it to know where the error is actually coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made things much more complicated than they need to be.

The model for your detail view should still be Playlist, not PlaylistEntry. The reason you're getting that error is that the slug is on the Playlist model, but you've told the view to filter on PlaylistEntry.

What you actually want to to is to pass the single Playlist identified by the slug into the template. From there, you can easily iterate through the detail objects associated with that playlist via the reverse relation.

So, change that model setting, and drop both `get_context_data` and `get_queryset` from the detail view: you don't need them. Then in the template you can simply do:

```
{% for entry in playlist.playlistentry_set.all %}
```

Comment: Thankyou very much Daniel - reverse relation was the ticket, so simple, and of course documented (Shamed to admit I had already read about it). Sometimes, as there is so much documentation, it can fill a newbie head full of the wrong way to do things also.